# MySQL Select Youngest child of user

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following problem.
I'd like to select the youngest kid of each customer and show the age of the kid. So, output has to look like this:

```
abc@example.com 12
cde@example.com 15
efg@example.com 8
```

If an ID has more than 1 kid, only the youngest kid should be shown.

```
Table "customers"
ID
Email


Table "kids"
ID
AgeOfKid
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the relation between the two tables?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: The relation is the ID

Comment: agree @waka, and what if we have two customers, man and woman with common kids ;)

Comment: if ID is relation, where is primary key on "kids"

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Include a couple of twins.

Comment: The information in your question is erroneous, unless the kids table has no primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the query you are looking for

```
 select c.Email,min(k.AgeOfKid) from customers c
 inner join kids k on k.ID=c.ID
 group by c.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no connection between the tables you should add foreign key customerId into kids table.
If there's already customerId in the kids table you can make a procedure that gives you back the data you need, instead of writing the query manually every time you need it. E.g of the procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getYoungestKid 
(
 findcustomerId INT
)
BEGIN
   SELECT c.email, MIN(k.AgeOfKId) AS 'youngest'
   FROM customers AS c JOIN kids AS k ON c.ID = k.customerId
   WHERE c.customerId = findcustomerId
   GROUP BY c.ID
END
```

To use the procedure just do :

```
CALL getYoungestKid (@customerId)
```

Where @customerId will be the ID of the customer you are searching the youngest kid for.

You can do a similar procedure for all the customers just get rid of findcustomerId as parameter and delete where clause at the end.